# Clear service worker cache from Android API

Tags: android, service-worker

We have a native andorid app with some webviews. We are using Service worker functionality in Android webviews.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/

Is there a way to clear out the service worker cache from the Android API? We want to specifically clear the cache when the user logs out from the Android app.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an Android developer, but the [`WebStorage#deleteAllData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html#deleteAllData()) method looks like it would accomplish what you'd want. If it doesn't, that sounds like a bug, and I'd recommend that you follow up via whatever mechanism is used for Android framework bugs.

Alternatively, and since I am a web developer, here's a JavaScript approach to clearing things out. Note that what you're referring to as a "service worker cache" isn't actually limited to service workers; the [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) is exposed in both the work global scope and as `window.caches`, so it would be used directly from the context of web pages. So you can run code that deletes all of the caches directly from a web page execution context, without jumping through hoops to trigger the service worker:

```
caches.keys()
  .then(cacheNames => Promise.all(cacheNames.map(cacheName => caches.delete(cacheName))))
  .then(() => console.log('Everything was deleted!'))
  .catch(error => console.warn('Something went wrong!', error));
```

Unlike the `WebStorage#deleteAllData()` call, that JavaScript will just clear the Cache Storage API, so the normal HTTP cache, as well as cookies and other site-specific storage will still remain.